# How to replace part of a text file between markers with another text file?

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script, textfiles, text-processors

Say I have a text file like this:

```
# custom content section
a
b

### BEGIN GENERATED CONTENT
c
d
### END GENERATED CONTENT
```

I'd like to replace the portion between the `GENERATED CONTENT` tags with the contents of another file.

What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
newContent=`cat new_file`
perl -0777 -i -pe "s/(### BEGIN GENERATED CONTENT\\n).*(\\n### END GENERATED CONTENT)/\$1$newContent\$2/s" existing_file
```

Answer (score 45):

```
lead='^### BEGIN GENERATED CONTENT$'
tail='^### END GENERATED CONTENT$'
sed -e "/$lead/,/$tail/{ /$lead/{p; r insert_file
        }; /$tail/p; d }"  existing_file
```

Comment: Excellent. `sed` can do so much more than just `s/.../...`!

Comment: Hmmm does not work for me, should I put the sed command on one line?

Comment: The `r insert_file` command must be the last thing on its line. *Note* that neither whitespace  nor comments are allowed after it. The code was tested using GNU `sed` with the `--posix` option enabled, and it worked as expected, so it should work with any *posix compliant* `sed`.

Comment: Holy moly, that's cool! This is going in my sed dictionary! Superbly useful and beautifully simple. Thank you!

Comment: Note an in-place editing requires you capture the output of sed (e.g. `output=$(sed -e "..." existing_file)`) and then perform the replacement in a second pass (e.g. `echo "$output" > existing_file`) since trying to redirect into a file you're reading from will cause it to truncate before contents are read.

Comment: can someone explain the command.

Comment: Note that it can fit on a single line by using two `-e "..."` expressions: `sed -e "[...] r insert_file" -e "}; [...]"`. The filename must be followed by the closing `"` without any space.

Comment: To clarify what @calandoa mentioned, the single-line version of the original is `sed -e "/$lead/,/$tail/{ /$lead/{p; r insert_file" -e "}; /$tail/p; d }" existing_file` 
To further clarify something that was slightly confusing me at first, both `insert_file` and `existing_file` are simply placeholders for the names/paths of actual files, and the combined file is output on stdout. To edit the file in-place instead, at least in GNU `sed`, add `--in-place` or `-i` (before `-e`, so `-i -e` **not** `-ie`), updating the `existing_file` with a replaced section in place.

Answer (score 6):

Using a heredoc and the ed line editor:

```
ed -s FILE1 <<EOF
/### BEGIN GENERATED/+,/### END GENERATED/-d
/### BEGIN GENERATED/ r FILE2
w
q
EOF
```

The first line inside the heredoc is to delete (`d`) the line after (`+`) the `### BEGIN GENERATED` and the line before (`-`) the `### END GENERATED...`

The second line is to insert `FILE2` after the line `### BEGIN GENERATED`.

Comment: Using a heredoc and the ed line editor. The first line inside the heredoc is to deleted 'd' the line after '+' the '### BEGIN gENERATED...' and the line before '-' the '### END GENERATED...' the second line is to insert FILE2 after the line ### END GENERATED...'

Comment: sorry what i meant was insert FILE2 after the line '### BEGIN GENERATED..'

Comment: Take it easy on me folks, it is after all my first time :-). Also i might have used the word the same but the other solution does not use a heredocs but a printf  and a pipe. Any way apologies if i have made a mistake :-)

Comment: Thanks, very readable! Btw - instead of `r FILE2` you can say `r !command` to read from a different script.

Answer (score 4):

Warning: This is definitely not the simplest way to do it. (EDIT: bash works; POSIX grep is fine too)

If the main text is in file "main" and the generated content is in file "gen", you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
BEGIN_GEN=$(cat main | grep -n '### BEGIN GENERATED CONTENT' | sed 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/g')
END_GEN=$(cat main | grep -n '### END GENERATED CONTENT' | sed 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/g')
cat <(head -n $(expr $BEGIN_GEN - 1) main) gen <(tail -n +$(expr $END_GEN + 1) main) >temp
mv temp main
```

Comment: Does this work? I think your last line will open `main` for writing, clearing it, before it is read by cat.

Comment: @chepner Crap, you're right. The rest works, though. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Bash script using
[ed line editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html)
to replace / update a part of multiline text in a text file with automatically
generated content (eg: Table of contents)

**replace.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#
# github   : https://github.com/JV-conseil
# www      : https://www.jv-conseil.net
# author   : JV-conseil
#===============================================

_lines=""

for i in {1..10}; do
  _lines+=$'\n'"${i}. ""$(openssl rand -hex 12)"
done

ed -s "./sample.md" <<EOF
/## BEGIN GENERATED/+,/## END GENERATED/-d
/## BEGIN GENERATED/a
${_lines}

.
wq
EOF
```

**sample.md**

```
# How to replace part of a text file between markers with another text file?

Here is a Bash script using [ed line editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html "GNU manual for ed line editor") to replace / update a part of multiline text in a text file with
automatically generated content (eg: Table of contents) 

## BEGIN GENERATED

1. d5c10e45943b196b005771f1
2. bc56de530fbf5342d55203b4
3. 9608f31a09c2ece9c9cee4dd
4. 54e361257aecce0a937211c0
5. c4b2edf88293df0747694c37
6. a80275accc9b2bc72d55efcd
7. 3a2e2fec5da23b415569de00
8. 524655319a05e7dd1f48e6a5
9. 879d17e9e611d163e5a85b02
10. 80d311a786efcd9d01da86f6

## END GENERATED

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris et libero eu nunc
dapibus volutpat. Proin eu neque eu orci volutpat bibendum...
```