# replace file's content between specific line numbers with another file using BASH

Tags: bash, text-editing

What is the most efficient way to replace file's content between specific line numbers with another file?

Here is a sample:

`main.txt`:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k l
```

`new.part.txt`

```
x y z
p q r
s t u
```

The block of text starting at line 2 and ending at line 3 of `main.txt` is replaced with `new.part.txt`. The desired file is as follow:

```
a b c
x y z
p q r
s t u
j k l
```

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/440057/222298) is for the case when range of the desired block is defined via marker strings. I need a solution that uses line numbers for defining range of the desired block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You don't use bash at all.

The Bourne Again shell is a shell.  The actual utility programs for doing this are not part of the shell, and are largely shell-agnostic.  `grawity`'s answer uses shell features, but mainly for parameterization.

Here's how to do it with `ex`, editing the file in place:

```
ex main.txt << EOT
2,3d
1r new.part.txt
w
EOT
```

Here's how one does it with `sed`, writing the changed data to standard output:

```
sed -e '1r new.part.txt' -e '2,3d' main.txt
```

Comment: ...and today I learn that ed & sed have the `r` command. Ouch.

Answer (score 2):

```
start=2
end=3

{
  head -n $((start-1)) old.txt
  cat new.txt
  tail -n $((end+1)) old.txt
} > merged.txt
```

Comment: I prefer this style, for readability. But looks like the `tail -n $((end+1)) old.txt` is not correct. You have to read in the number of lines of the file, and subtract your end position. `tail -n $(($(wc -l < old.txt)-end)) old.txt`