# conversion from GNU sed to BSD sed

Tags: sed, bsd

I am new to sed and am trying to implement [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/440057/861996) on a mac. After some quick research I believe I have to convert the code to BSD sed. I haven't had much success looking into the BSD sed documentation and am looking for help on how to proceed.

Comment: Sometimes it’s easier to use Homebrew to install the GNU version of a tool than to bother with syntax differences. Also note that BSD tools that use regex often use an older traditional version of regex syntax unless you pass them `-E` for extended regex.

Comment: Add a semi-colon after the `d`

Comment: Why don't you use `perl` in accordance to the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/440032/700617)?

Comment: Or just follow @Thor's advice. No need to *convert code*.